# Can I bring a turret through the teleporter at the end of Entanglement?

Tags: half-life-2

In the *Half-Life 2* chapter *Entanglement*, one can bring along two turrets from first turret standoff all the way to the teleporter where you escape with Alyx.  Is it possible to bring them further, out of Nova Prospekt, and into *Anti-Citizen One*?

Comment: Is this on the PC version?

Comment: @Batophobia does it matter?

Comment: @NickT If it was you could use console commands to give yourself a turret at the start of the next level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not.  At least not without cheating.  I have tried this, by carrying a turret in with me through the slow-teleport.  Sadly, while the extra turrets make a great defense at the final stand-off, you can't take them with you into the near-future.

Comment: Also, GLaDOS would not approve.